# Display text on large screen and icon on small screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a menu like

```
<ul id='menu'>
            <li id='home' ><a href='index.php'><span class='menu_text'>Home</span><img class='menu_icon' src='_images/icons.svg#svg_home' alt=''/></a></li>
            <li id='other'><a href='other.php'><span class='menu_text'>others</span><img class='menu_icon' src='_images/icons.svg#others' alt=''/></a></li>
            ...
            </ul>
```

Now I want to display text with class `menu_text` when the screen size is large i.e on laptops and `menu_icon` should remain hidden and the reverse when screen size is small i.e on tablets or mobile devices how can I achive it using css ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use css `@media queries`.

**Large screens:**

```
  @media only screen and (min-width:1024px){

    .menu_text { display: block; }
    .menu_icon { display: none; }

  }
```

**Smaller screen**

```
  @media only screen and (max-width:480px){

    .menu_text { display: none; }
    .menu_icon { display: block; }

  }
```

You could change the max and min width values to ones that fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

For example, you could hide the menu text like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .menu_text {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using media query.

**CSS**

```css
#menu img {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
/*For Ipad Portrait view and below that*/
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 #menu span {
   display: none;
 }
  #menu img {
  display: block;
} 
}
```

```html
<ul id='menu'>
            <li id='home' ><a href='index.php'><span class='menu_text'>Home</span><img class='menu_icon' src='_images/icons.svg#svg_home' alt='menu_icon'/></a></li>
            <li id='other'><a href='other.php'><span class='menu_text'>others</span><img class='menu_icon' src='_images/icons.svg#others' alt='others'/></a></li>
            
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link and download it.
[Responsive Retina-Ready Menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/08/responsive-retina-ready-menu/)

and after that just add this media to the index.html page in head part

```
<style>
        @media(min-width:504px)
        {
            .icon{
                display:none !important;
            }
        }
        </style>
```